# Setting and retrieveing value from javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, typescript

I have just started using javascript and would like to ask a question (obviously :P)
I have written two methods, one that gets value from an object, based on its data path (data path being structure within an object, like this: "object.subObject.anotherSubObject.property"), and another that sets a value to a object based on the data path.

Here is that code written in typescript:

```
public getValueFromObject(object:any, path:string|string[], thisArg:any = null):any {
    thisArg = thisArg == null ? this : thisArg;
    var value:any = null;
    if (object == null || object == undefined || object == "undefined")
        return value;
    if (path == null || path == undefined || path == "undefined" || path == "")
        return value;
    if (typeof path == "string" && !Array.isArray(path)) {
        path = (<string>path).split(".");
    }
    var currPath:string = path[0];
    if (path.length > 1 && object.hasOwnProperty(currPath)) {
        value = thisArg.getValueFromObject(object[currPath], path.slice(1), thisArg);
    }
    else if (object.hasOwnProperty(currPath)) {
        value = object[currPath];
    }
    return value;
}

private setValueToObject(dataObject:any, value:any, dataPath:string|string[], thisArg:any = null):any {
    thisArg = thisArg == null ? this : thisArg;
    if (dataObject == null || dataObject == undefined || dataObject == "undefined")
        return null;
    if (dataPath == null || dataPath == undefined || dataPath == "undefined" || dataPath == "")
        return null;
    if (typeof dataPath == "string" && !Array.isArray(dataPath)) {
        dataPath = (<string>dataPath).split(".");
    }
    var currPath:string = dataPath[0];
    if (dataPath.length > 1) {
        if (!dataObject.hasOwnProperty(currPath)) {
            dataObject[currPath] = {};
        }
        dataObject[currPath] = thisArg.setValueToObject(dataObject[currPath], value, dataPath.slice(1), thisArg);
    }
    else {
        dataObject[currPath] = value;
    }
    return dataObject;
}
```

Now, I would like to know, is this a well written javascript code, and are there any libraries that could do the same thing I'm trying to achieve? Maybe lodash? And would really appreciate if someone would provide an example code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have to ask, why would you need to get and set the value of an object like this when you can just do it normally

Comment: Well, what is the "normal" way :D
And to answer, I need to have a certain structure of objects when I send request to my backend. And this is the most convenient "generic" way I can think of. Just pass an array of strings (or one string) and a value.

Comment: Going to put in the answer as code in the comments is a frowny face situation

Answer (score -1):

Objects are pretty malleable with javascript as it is.

Start an object

```
var myobj = {
    var1: 'hello'
}
```

Get var1

```
console.log(myobj.var1) // 'hello'
```

Set var1

```
myobj.var1 = 'world'
```

Get var1 again

```
console.log(myobj.var1) // 'world'
```

Bring it all together to output 'hello world' to your console

```
var myobj = { var1: 'hello' };
console.log(myobj.var1);
myobj.var1 = 'world';
console.log(myobj.var1);
```

Other than that your code looks pretty ok. There is "more than way to skin a cat" and by no means is one way better than another when programming for fun. It is good to write things like you did for good practice. You should also be aware of faster ways to improve your code in production though.

Comment: Well, the problem with that is, I don't always know what the object structure will look like. So I'am using these "generic" functions that create objects from string paths. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: Sure man, sounds good. What works for you best is what works best for you.

Comment: "You should also be aware of faster ways to improve your code in production though."

Can you please share some thoughts on that? Or perhaps point me to some tips&tricks javascript resources for writing production value code?

I am trying to learn and get better at this, since my background is mostly c#, AS3, java and c++ :)

Comment: I taught myself javascript so I might not be helpful there. I learned javascript objects when I found google chromes console log and started typing in all these weird things like 'window' and saw when i typed a dot it wanted to offer me more items. I went through every single item I could to see what they did.